SSIS Package Generates Correct File Name in SSDT, but SQL Server Agent Job Uses Default Name
I have an SSIS package that generates a CSV output file with a dynamically generated name based on the current date and time. The expression for the file name is set in the FilePath variable within the package. When I run the package from SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), the file is named correctly as per the expression.
However, when I schedule the same package to run via a SQL Server Agent job, the output file name reverts to the default name without the dynamic parts included. It seems like the expressions or variables are not being applied when the package is executed by the SQL Server Agent job.
Setup Details:
The package is stored in the SSISDB.
The SQL Server Agent job runs under a domain account that has Read and Write permissions on the output folder.
The job step is configured to use the package from the SSISDB with no additional parameters set.
What could be causing the SQL Server Agent job to ignore the dynamic file name expression set in the SSIS package and revert to the default file name? How can I ensure that the file name is generated correctly when the package is run by SQL Server Agent?

In the job could you be overriding one of the  variables for the package?

Check the scope of the variable is set to (from memory) package, not user.

@Brad, how? where to check for that?

@AlanSchofield Scope is set to Package. I don't see any option to change it to user.

Go to the job open it and click the step that is executing the package.  Then click Configuration tab in middle of the popup.  Then click Advanced.  If there is a Property Path filled out in the middle section, that overrides variable values.

@Brad, Thanks, but nothing is there. should I maybe add something in here then?
